# gvim swaping between underline and normal visual text selection in visual mode

Tags: gvim, visual-mode, selection

I'm having a weird issue running gvim 8.2.1081 on fedora 32 using kde. When selecting text in visual mode gvim keeps swapping between an underline and the expected visual text selection while moving the cursor.

[image: underline]

[image: correct visual text selection]

In both images all the text is selected.

Gvim was installed using the vim-X11 package.

At first I thought it was the colorscheme, but changing it didn't work.

Any suggestions on how to fix it or what may be causing the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Looks like `:h hl-VisualNOS`

Comment: You were absolutely right Matt, thank you so much didn't know about that

Answer (score 1):

Responding For Future Reference.

It was indeed the VisualNOS highlight, fixed it by making VisualNOS highlight match Visual highlight and removing the underline.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you edit this to say what command you used?  I ended up doing this by `:hi VisualNOS <arguments>` and using the mouse to select and paste the arguments that are displayed by `:hi Visual` - but notably not including the `xxx` that is shown for display purposes.  But it was tricky to figure it out.